# How to remove gap in adobe Illustrator Pattern brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am following one tutorial. There the tutor draws a rollercoaster in Ai. I try to draw the same. my understanding is she used a pattern brush to draw the rollercoaster. (She didn't show tho how did she draw it)  But my brush pattern shows a gap. I changed the setting and applied it to stroke but it does not go away. How can I remove it?

and in her rollercoaster, she has a nice perspective view. is it possible through the brush? or she has hand drawn that?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove last vertical beam or draw a bounding box around it

Comment: I don't believe a brush is going to narrow like that (unless you use the Width Tool).. If you look closely at the tutorial screenshot you can see the cross bars *often* extend outside the "rails". I believe it *may be* all individual paths.

Comment: Or a brush which was expanded and then tweaked.

Comment: @joojaa It works. thank you.

Comment: @Scott No way I can achieve her finishing! :'( am sad. my width tool impacts a wide area! :'(  am keep trying :"(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following on from Scott and Joojaa's hints, remove the last sleeper from the rail brush.

Use the Width tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to narrow or widen the applied brush.

[image]